# javascript move div elements in parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a block that I will drag and I need the borders of this block not to go beyond the document, that is, when moving the mouse outside the browser window, the block should hit the border and just follow the mouse pointer

css of block

```
  position: fixed;
  top: 140px;
  left: 150px;
```

example of code allow drag element

```
const rect = this._draggableContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
this._draggableContainer.style.left = rect.x + event.movementX + 'px'
```

Expected result, the block hits the walls of the document and does not crawl out of the him
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoFrV.png)

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle?

Comment: You better store the container and pointer positions in the mousedown event and than calculate the pointer delta and add it to the container's initial position in the mousemove event. This will allow you to check if the new position is within the limits and decide to stop the container if the calculated position passes beyond the edges of the container. Please provide a minimal working code so you get more chance to get further help.

Comment: I would check out [mcve]